# xcode (version 9.2) not showing crash logs for TestFlight Beta versions

Tags: ios, xcode

in my Xcode menubar -> Window -> Organizer -> (select my app) -> Crashes :

There are nice crash logs for "AppStore -> Release" versions, but no crash logs for "AppStore -> Beta" version.  I do see the selections but when select them, it shows empty logs that I should not be.

I do use TestFlight for testing.  Isn't the "AppStore -> Beta above for TestFlight Beta testing?  I must be missing something to enable the crash logs for the TestFlight non-released versions?

Please share any pointers and thanks in advance.

My Xcode version is 9.2

Comment: In my testing of this feature it can take 24 hours for crashes to appear there.